# vba - Workbooks.Add(template) failing with out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a new workbook based on the formatting as that of an existing excel file and i am using the below code

```
sub newWorkBook()    
Dim newWorkBook as New WorkBook
Set newWorkBook = WorkBooks.Add("Template.xls")
/*It is erroring on the above line*/
                newWorkBook.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                With newWorkBook
                    .SaveAs "C:\new.xls"
                End With
                domainWorkBook.Save
                domainWorkBook.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                domainWorkBook.Close
                Set newWorkBook = Nothing
End Sub
```

It errors on the line `Set newWorkBook = WorkBooks.Add("Template.xls")` saying subscript out of range..

It also opens a new excel named Template1.xls and throws error...Any suggestions?

Comment: This is an educated guess - unless the file you are trying to create your new workbook from is open at the time you are trying to make this happen, or it is located in the default file path, you may want to qualify the workbook name with its full pathname

Answer (score 0):

Why not just open the *Template* and *SaveAs* a new name?

```
Sub qwerty()
    Workbooks.Open "C:\TestFolder\Template.xls"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\TestFolder\new.xls"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh..I just realized that even the `Workbooks.open` is erroring with subscript out of range error..I am sure that file is there

Comment: Make absolutely sure the complete filespec is correct and you have **permission** to open the file.